# PHP Curl Call when executed outputs an HTML content where as JSON was expected

Tags: php, json, curl

When i do a curl call using php which is as shown below

```
<?php
$username = "XXXX";
$password = "XXXX";
$url = "https://domainname/method";
$ch = curl_init();
$fullAddress="202 220 GEORGE ST";

$payload = json_encode( array( "payload"=>[array("fullAddress"=>$fullAddress)],
                               "sourceOfTruth"=>'AUPAF'));


//var_dump($payload);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json','Accept: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,           true ); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload );
# Return response instead of printing.
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
# Send request.
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$err = curl_error($ch); 
curl_close($ch);

 echo '<pre>', htmlentities($result), '</pre>'; 

$json = json_decode($result, true); 

?>
```

it outputs an weird response saying that

```
  <html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/7.0.52 (Ubuntu) - Error report</title><style><!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:whi
```

I'm actually stuck up with it for several hours so any suggestions would be helpfull

Comment: It looks like your webserver is throwing an error. Please check the logs.

Comment: You are getting an error report back from the server, are you sure all parameters and urls where as expected by the API?

Comment: the webserver is handled by the api provider. i'm consuming using restrequest with curl

Comment: Maybe read through the error message? Who knows it gives you a more detailed description of what might be happening.

Comment: they had given the url and parameters they had asked me to pass parameters as json payload which i had done in the format expected.

Comment: the problem is the error message stops there it doesn't show anything more than that

Comment: Well that is a bommer indeed, are you sure this is what the server expacts though? `json_encode( array( "payload"=>[array("fullAddress"=>$fullAddress)], "sourceOfTruth"=>'AUPAF'));` might it be `json_encode(  ['payload' => [['fullAddress' => $fullAddress], ['sourceOfTruth' => 'AUPAF']]]  );` ?

Comment: Nope there expected format was {
        "payload": [ { "fullAddress": "L 2 SE 202 220 GEORGE ST" } ],
        "sourceOfTruth": "AUPAF"
    }  so when i did a var_dump i got the same value(i have commented the vardump  in the above code)

Comment: I've placed my suggestion as answer, it might be better readable now, and I included some tips. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I've post a comment, but I recon that it's not very well readable.

Here is my suggestion, to use for nested arrays:

```
json_encode( [ 'payload' => [
                    ['fullAddress'   => $fullAddress]
               ], 
               'sourceOfTruth' => 'AUPAF'

              ] );
```

In your example your arrays where further nested, maybe the server does not expact this.

A few other tips:

1. Make sure the URL to the API is correct.
2. The headers send to the server are as expected.
3. the credentials you entered, are they right? might this be a permission issue?
4. Shouldn't the password be `base64_encode`'d?

Also try just printing all content, and accept text/html for a bit. Just to see what the error message might be.